# print charts using plotly in a for-loop on jupyterlab doesn't behave as expected？

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a question for python plotly package.

In order to make it clear, I give a short example below.

I have a list which contains 4 sub-lists, what I want to do is to print a bar chart for each sub-list, so I use a for-loop and call fig.show() for each.

But the output is not what I expect, the 4 for-iteration printed out are all the same chart(look at the title I highlighted in the screenshot), can I know what happens here?

BTW fig.write_html works fine, and if I add time.sleep(2), it works too.

### My env

```
matplotlib==3.6.2
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
plotly==5.7.0
jupyter-events==0.6.3
jupyter_client==8.0.2
jupyter_core==5.2.0
jupyter_server==2.1.0
jupyter_server_terminals==0.4.4
jupyterlab==3.5.3
jupyterlab-pygments==0.2.2
jupyterlab-widgets==3.0.5
jupyterlab_server==2.19.0
```

```py
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "iframe"

ys = [
    [2, 3, 1], 
    [1, 2, 2], 
    [4, 2, 3], 
    [3, 2, 5]
]

for y in ys:
    title = '-'.join([str(i) for i in y])
    fig = go.Figure(
        data=[go.Bar(y=y)],
        layout_title_text=title
    )
    # fig.write_html(f'./{title}.html', include_plotlyjs=True)
    fig.show()
    # time.sleep(2)
```

[image]

Comment: Would disabling iFrame improve this?

Comment: @r-beginners no, the chart won't show up if I don't put "iframe" there.

Comment: Your screenshot clearly shows you are usiing Jupyter to do this but it isn't mentioned in your post or as a tag for the post. It helps the right people, meaning both people helping you and others with the same issue, find your post to help you if you make posts thorough and not rely on data in the screenshots that aren't used for building the search database. In this case your screenshot though doesn't include information on which Jupyter interface. When I was first investigating, I thought(?) I was seeing what you saw when running the code in JupyterLab ...

Comment: <continued> , and not the classic notebook interface. So it seemed pertinent. But maybe not. I usually assume not JupyterLab unless specified.

Comment: I do sort of wonder if it is network thing because I definitely see differences. I know it seemed like it was working in one interface and not the other. And the pause could be consistent with that. Plus the differences with your code in the weird output that the two interfaces show. The two interfaces could be differently sensitive to the time of the data coming in by slightly?

Comment: By 'networking' I more mean maybe an internal communication route or some other sort of race condition between javascript and something in the backend?

Comment: Thanks @Wayne for the reply, I edited the title and added tag jupyter and jupyterlab. It should not be network issue because the jupyter is launched in intranet.

Comment: Well in the past, Plotly used to connect back to Plotly to deposit your information. I don't know if that is still the case if you use a key or not. And what it does when not using a user key.  So that is why I was thinking 'network'-likem and sort of mis-typed. But more broadly it seems like an internal issue with cross-talk timing or race situation. Adding a pause and causing it to work is really consistent with that.

Comment: @Wayne yes, that's what I think too, but interesting thing was if I ran the same code on other servers (in the same intranet), it worked.... the only difference was they're classic jupyter not jupyterlab, but I don't think that's the case, I did remember it worked on jupyterlab earlier, just not worked on this one.

Comment: But with the pause it works in JupyterLab though, right? JupyterLab has it's own server backend, I believe. So it reasonable that it may be in one and not the other. I'm asking whether adding the pause fixes it because maybe it's worth it to file [an issue in JupyterLab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues) mentioning this and highlighting that workaround in the post.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed bizarre. Uncommenting that line for the second pause fixes your code. Weird. (Although I'd say it is more consistent with the non-working code when the pause is placed before the `fig.show()` line. But either work.)

You can see the same thing for yourself **without need to touch your computer or install anything**. Go [here](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder) and click `launch binder`. When it opens run the code from the original post in the classic notebook interface. Then click on the Jupyter logo in the upper right and you'll be switched to the JupyterLab interface. Run that code in a new notebook there. (You can switch back to classic from JupyterLab by using 'Help' along the File menubar and selecting 'Launch Classic Notebook'.) Once you see the weirdness, you can try the provided options, such as adding the pause, **after restarting the kernel**.

---

One things I have a problem with was your assertion that the chart doesn't show up with the iframe line? I am not seeing that be the case.

This below works in both interfaces and the bar charts show up where I reference above (I simply removed `pio.renderers.default = "iframe"`:

```py
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio


ys = [
    [2, 3, 1], 
    [1, 2, 2], 
    [4, 2, 3], 
    [3, 2, 5]
]

for y in ys:
    title = '-'.join([str(i) for i in y])
    fig = go.Figure(
        data=[go.Bar(y=y)],
        layout_title_text=title
    )
    # fig.write_html(f'./{title}.html', include_plotlyjs=True)
    fig.show()
    # time.sleep(2)
```

In fact, I don't see the purpose of importing `plotly.pio` or `matplotlib` either. Maybe for other things in your notebook you need them?

---

These simpler variations also work. Putting them here because may be useful for testing:

A few things, such as [this](https://github.com/plotly/plotly_express/issues/144#issuecomment-535492352) suggest it is easy like you suppose. I tried switching to Plotly express since that old issue used it. Here is that code:

```py
import plotly.express as px

ys = [
    [2, 3, 1], 
    [1, 2, 2], 
    [4, 2, 3], 
    [3, 2, 5]
]

for y in ys:
    px.bar(y=y, title='-'.join([str(i) for i in y])).show()
```

This variation on yours:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

ys = [
    [2, 3, 1], 
    [1, 2, 2], 
    [4, 2, 3], 
    [3, 2, 5]
]

for y in ys:
    title = '-'.join([str(i) for i in y])
    fig = go.Figure(
        data=[go.Bar(y=y)],
        layout_title_text=title
    )
    fig.show()
```

I was going to suggest a workaround based on [Plotly subplots](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/), but I realized it was not necessarily necessary. But maybe would work, if `plotly.io`, `matplotlib`, and the iframe do need to be there. And maybe more robust, or at least logical, then adding pause workaround.

Comment: I just ran the same code in a classic jupyter, and all work fine, have no idea what happens to the juypterlab. I imported "plotly.io" for iframe stuff, imported "matplotlib" because matplotlib has some function like close()/flush(), they are used to clear the cache thing, I was looking for the same thing in plotly if can help to fix the issue.